# How to get rid of these illegal characters ?

Tags: php, illegal-characters

   Apple
   Bat
   Cat
   Rat
   Mat
   Fat

I want to get rid of these illegal characters. Can you suggest some solution. I am using php as programming language.

These appears when i paste something from MS word to textarea of html page.

Comment: [What You Need to Know About Encodings and Character Sets to Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) by [Deceze](http://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze).

Comment: Its not what i want. something out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to extract the ASCII, then you could try this:

`$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $string);`

Comment: I already found it on google and stackoverflow, but didnt worked out. Hence posted question here

Comment: It works when I test it. Are you looking to use only a few unicode characters?

Comment: It might worked for you but not working for me. :(
My task is that user will paste anything from a wordfile to textarea in html page. I just want illegal characters to be filtered.

Comment: when you try: `$string = " Apple  Bat  Cat  Rat  Mat  Fat"; echo($string . "<br/>");
$string = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $string);
echo($string . "<br/>");`, does it not work. Also, what are you illegal characters?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [String replace](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). I assume that you're trying to process submitted form data, and want to sanitize the textarea value to remove these characters.

```
$retrievedAreaText = $_POST["textAreaId"];
$illegalChars = array("",); //others
$retrievedAreaText = str_replace($illegalChars,"",$retrievedAreaText);
//further processing
```

Comment: I am aware of it and this solution wont work out in any case for 2 reasons.
1) This is not the only illegal character. It can be any as the user will paste it from word file to textarea
2) Text Editor(Notepad++) doesnt show this character.

Comment: (1) so add the other illegal characters to the array.
(2) so? If you know the characters you're trying to blacklist, put them into the array. If your text editor can't display them, look up their ASCII/Unicode values. If you want to take a white list approach, then define the white list of acceptable characters and replace all values not in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this one:

```
$string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
```

It converts special characters to utf standards or in any standard that yo want.
It is real that special chars mostly are trouble.

Hope this helps you.